# analyze incoming data independent of client.on in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have correctly set-up a client using 
var client = net.Socket()
and 
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {...}

The
client.on('data', function(data) {...} 
piece of code captures the incomming data correctly.

So far so good.

I want to use the client.on routine only to store the incoming data in a buffer.  If the next datagram is captured, it will be stored as a next element in the buffer.

I want to analyze the data in the buffer in a different subroutine for as long as there are elements in the buffer.  When one element of the buffer is analyzed, this element will be removed from the buffer, and this goes on until the buffer is empty.  This needs to run asynchroneously and independently.

What would be the best way to do this ?

Comment: Just do exactly what you proposed... keep a buffer around of incoming data and process it.  What is your specific question?  Have you looked at the streams API?

Comment: Brad thanks.  My specific question is what will trigger the execution of the subroutine that will analyze the datagrams that were captured in the buffer.  Intercepting the datagrams is done by the client.on('data', function(data) {...} code, but then, how do i trigger the code to analyze what is storred in the buffer